Is there a way to automatically overload functions with a 1-to-1 input-output type correspondence?
Let's say I have this function
from typing import reveal_type


def func(x: str | list[str]) -> int | list[int]:
    """
    Some docstring that should show up.
    """
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return 0
    return list(range(len(x)))


y = func(["hi", "hello"])
reveal_type(y)  # int | list[int]

Revealing y's type / hovering over it in your IDE will tell you int | list[int].
To make y's type more precise, we overload it:
from typing import overload, reveal_type


@overload
def func(x: str) -> int: ...


@overload
def func(x: list[str]) -> list[int]: ...


def func(x: str | list[str]) -> int | list[int]:
    """
    Some docstring that should show up.
    """
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return 0
    return list(range(len(x)))


y = func(["hi", "hello"])
reveal_type(y)  # list[int]

Now, y's revealed type is list[int].
I have many of these sort of functions—ones where the possible return types have a 1-to-1 correspondence with the types of a single input of the function. Ideally, I'd just have to do something like—
from typing import UnionMatch  # not a real thing


def func(x: UnionMatch[str, list[str]]) -> UnionMatch[int, list[int]]:
    """
    Some docstring that should show up.
    """
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return 0
    return list(range(len(x)))

—to be precise about the return type. No @overloads needed.
How can this sort of functionality be achieved?
User kevdog824 on Reddit has a solution here and here for the case where there are exactly 2 types in the UnionMatch:
from typing import (
    reveal_type,
    Callable,
    Concatenate,
    Generic,
    overload,
    ParamSpec,
    TypeVar,
)


_C1 = TypeVar("_C1")
_C2 = TypeVar("_C2")
_P = ParamSpec("_P")
_T1 = TypeVar("_T1")
_T2 = TypeVar("_T2")


class FuncTemplate(Generic[_C1, _C2, _P, _T1, _T2]):

    def __init__(self, func: Callable[Concatenate[_C1 | _C2, _P], _T1 | _T2]) -> None:
        self.func = func
        # self.__call__.__doc__ = func.__doc__
        # Not correct b/c:
        # AttributeError: attribute '__doc__' of 'method' objects is not writable

    @overload
    def __call__(
        self,
        common_input: _C1,
        *args: _P.args,
        **kwargs: _P.kwargs,
    ) -> _T1: ...

    @overload
    def __call__(
        self,
        common_input: _C2,
        *args: _P.args,
        **kwargs: _P.kwargs,
    ) -> _T2: ...

    def __call__(
        self,
        common_input: _C1 | _C2,
        *args: _P.args,
        **kwargs: _P.kwargs,
    ) -> _T1 | _T2:
        return self.func(common_input, *args, **kwargs)


@FuncTemplate
def func(x: str | list[str]) -> int | list[int]:
    """
    Some docstring that should show up.
    """
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return 0
    return list(range(len(x)))


y = func(["hi", "hello"])
reveal_type(y)  # list[int]


z = func("hey")
reveal_type(z)  # int

A dealbreaker is that the function's docstring is lost. Hovering over the function in my IDE (I believe it uses Pylance) says
(function) func: FuncTemplate[str, list[str], (), int, list[int]]

I haven't been able to get @functools.wraps working here. And ideally, there's a solution that works with more than 2 types in the UnionMatch.

There's no way of doing this cleanly in Python without overloading, as far as I know. If that's right, you're effectively asking for recommendations for libraries or frameworks that would give you this (I did not vote down, as I'm not 100%). However, it seems to be an edge case, and I would argue overloading is the better solution in the overwhelming majority of cases. The level of flexibility for which you want a feature probably should be rare, since it goes against the single responsibility principle - or otherwise it would likely be clear how to type the parameters.

@Grismar OP is asking how to make a specific tool produce a specific output, which, I believe, is on-topic. In this specific case, there is not even one library/framework that could do such a thing, since the tool in question is doing static analysis using only its own internal logic. To OP: this is likely to be very difficult, if not impossible, and since we are talking about internal logic, the result isn't guaranteed: it might break when you update Pyright/Pylance. Better stick to the norm and write each @overload manually.

First of all, the snippet you got is invalid - there is no way to split A | B back into A and B, and the fact that pyright does that is, uhm, disgusting.

Every programming language makes a design choice about how sophisticated its type system is. A type is a set of values, so loosely speaking, reasoning about types has lower fidelity than reasoning about values. What you're asking for is crossing into the territory of dependent types, which only exists in a few languages, and is not without its own complexities.
